# Dependence of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

I need to solve the following problem:

Let X be a normal random variable with mean  and standard deviation  and let I, independent of X, be such that P{I = 2} = P{I = -2} = 0.5. Let Y = I X. In words, Y is equally likely to be either 2X or –2X. 
a)  Are X and Y independent?
b)  Are I and Y independent?
c)  What is the distribution of Y?
d)  Find Cov(X,Y).

I think X and Y are dependent but I don't know how to formally prove it. Where should I start? Also, what about the following points?

Answer (score 1):

To show that two random variables $X,Y$ are not independent, it suffices to show that the there exist sets $S, T$ such that $$P(Y\in T)\neq P(Y\in T|X \in S)$$ It is easy to find such sets in the above exercise. For example $$P(Y>8|0<X<3)=0$$ whereas $$P(Y>8)>0$$ so that $Y$ and $X$ are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some information about the value of $Y$, it gives you information about the value of $X$. By definition, it means they are dependent.

Regarding $I$ and $Y$: It depends on the expected value of $X$; If it is $0$, then knowing the value of $I$ doesn't change the distribution of $Y$, since the density function of $X$ is even. Otherwise, fixing a value of $I$ does change the distribution of $Y$.

For the distribution of $Y$, note that $$P(Y\leq a)=\frac{1}{2}P(X\leq\frac{a}{2})+\frac{1}{2}P(X\geq-\frac{a}{2}).$$ The covariance can be calculated directly by the above.

Comment: Nice answer +1.